# how to write footnote citation in beamer in one line?

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer latex and I need to give reference in the footnote. My reference is about 2 lines. but when I write the following code it writes it in more lines!!!

```
\documentclass[landscape]{beamer}                           
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}                            
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

 \begin{frame}
 \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
  Huo et al. \footfullcite{Huo, et al. ``Computerized analysis of digitized mammograms of BRCA1 and BRCA2 gene mutation carriers 1.'' Radiology 225, no. 2 (2002): 519-526.}said that:
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

the output is like this:

```
Huo,
et al. ”Prediction of clinical phenotypes in invasive breast carcinomas from the integration of radiomics and genomics data.”
no. 4 (2015): 041007-041007..
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem might be, that latex has problems to hyphenate the title of the article. An easy workaround is to let latex do the work and use `bibtex` or `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% only for this example, otherwise in .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Huo2002,
    author = {Zhimin Huo and Maryellen L. Giger and Olufunmilayo I. Olopade and Dulcy E. Wolverton and Barbara L. Weber and Charles E. Metz and Weiming Zhong and Shelly A. Cummings},
    title = {Computerized Analysis of Digitized Mammograms of BRCA1 and BRCA2 Gene Mutation Carriers},
    journal = {Radiology},
    volume = {225},
    number = {2},
    pages = {519-526},
    year = {2002},
    doi = {10.1148/radiol.2252010845},
    note ={PMID: 12409590},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{R: Literature Review}
    \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
    Huo et al. \footfullcite{Huo2002}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]